# How to listen to country select change

Tags: select2

How can I listen in JavaScript to the event of a country value change on the country select field?

both #select2-drop-mask and #select2-drop are not available until the user clicks to open the select.

and the hidden select #country-5 is not firing the change event as its values are set programatically.

This question was asked [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4221/capture-country-field-selection-with-js-jquery) but has a wrong answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below code:

```
  CRM.$(function($) {
    $('#billing_country_id-5').change(function () {
      var countryId = $(this).val();
    });
  });
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Yes! thank you! oh I've been working on this for hours!

Answer (score 2):

In general, when you want to listen to an event on a select2 you place the listener on the original form element (which is either an `<input>` or a `<select>`). When inspecting the dom, you'll see it close to the select2 div, hidden because it has the `select2-offscreen` class.